# Returning documents with an async query in a foreach loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm forEaching over an object to find id numbers, to then look up and return the related documents from mongodb.

I'm able to console the documents within the forEach function, but I can't return them, and I'm struggling to understand why. This is my function....

```
let myFunction = projects.people.forEach(async function (person) {
    const outputs = await Output.find({ person: person._id })
    console.log(outputs) // this works
    return outputs
})
console.log(myFunction) // this does not work
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if this is because it's async, or a forEach (I tried it with for/of and couldn't get that to return outside the function either) . What's the best way to return these documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to create an array of ids and then use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to find all of them in just one query. Something like:

```
let myFunction = await Output.find({ 
  person: {
    $in: projects.people.map(person => person._id) 
  }
});
console.log(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 2):

forEach is not async you can use for loop

```
  for (const person of persons ) {
    const outputs = await Output.find({ person: person['id']  })
    console.log(outputs) // this works
    return outputs
  }
```

Comment: @bevc did you try this solution? I am just curious!

Comment: @Adeel Nawaz, you are a life saver, I followed your snippet and it worked for my use case. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try `map`

```
let myFunction = projects.people.map(async function (person) {
    const outputs = await Output.find({ person: person._id })
    console.log(outputs) // this works
    return outputs
})
console.log(myFunction)
```

Comment: I tried this, I'm afraid it didn't work, it just returns (person) number of empty objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call log in an async function if you want to log the combined output.

```js
const Output =  {
   find(obj) {
    return obj;
  }
}

const projects = {
  people: [{
    _id: 1
  }, {
    _id: 2
  }]
}

const myFunction = async() => Promise.all(projects.people.map(person => Output.find({
  person: person._id
})));

async function log() {
  console.log(await myFunction());
}

log();
```